# Google App Engine and Python Connected Project

Tags: java, android, python, eclipse, google-app-engine

Currently I am using Eclipse and I am trying to implement a Python Backend/API for an Android App on Google App Engine.

I see you can generate an App Engine Backend using Google Eclipse Plugins but from I see it can only be generated in Java. **Is there a way to generate an App Engine Backend in Python?**

**Would it be better to create a Python App Engine Project and define all the API associated with the App in that project and just make calls through another project that houses the app itself?**'

Just looking for some clarification as to how the best way to organize and implement this type of project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse plugin is Java only. However you can use your favorite IDE to work with app engine and it works really fine. If you do like eclipse, add the app engine libraries to your project. And create a run configuration as follows:

${project_loc}   or some other flags

More info here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse

Please note that you can use the App Engine console to lauch/stop your project and code using your favorite IDE too, there is no need to configure eclipse to launch (it is just more comfortable to do so)

Comment: Okay, I think i understand now. I can deploy the Python API in any manner, but when I make calls to the API through endpoints it has to be done under one project where the endpoint libraries have been generated.